# Python Class instantiation: What does it mean when a class is called without accompanying arguments?

Tags: python, class

I am trying to understand some code that I have found on github. Essentially there is a class called "HistoricCSVDataHandler" that has been imported from another module. In the main method this class is passed as a parameter to another class "backtest".

How can a class name that does not represent a instantiated variable be called without raising a NameError.

Or simply put :

Why/How is the class being called as:

```
Backtest(HistoricCSVDataHandler)
```

Rather than:

```
CSV_Handler = HistoricCSVDataHandler(foo,bar,etc)
Backtest(CSV_Handler)
```

[See line 110 for code.](https://github.com/djunh1/event-driven-backtesting/blob/master/snp_forecast.py)

Regards

Comment: Most likely because they want to compose the `HistoricCSVDataHandler` class in an instance of `Backtest`. You should check the `__init__` method of `Backtest` to be sure

Comment: Classes are objects like any other. They're not special in python. You can pass them around like numbers, strings, functions or what have you. Perhaps `Backtest` then creates an instance of the class it receives as argument. A class name is just a variable name like any other, also. Importing it just introduces the name in the namespace doing the import and binds the imported value to it.

Comment: Classes are objects in Python. *Everything* is an object in Python. We can only guess at the motivation without seeing the code, but it's not particularly exotic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a technique called [*dependency injection*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection). A class is an object just like any other, so there's nothing wrong with passing it as an argument to a function and then calling it inside the function.

Suppose I want to read a string and get either an `int` or a `float` back. I could write a function that takes the desired class as an argument:

```
def convert(s, typ):
    return typ(s)
```

Calling this gives several possibilities:

```
>>> convert(3, str)
'3'
>>> convert('3', int)
3
>>> convert('3', float)
3.0
```

So the `Backtest` function in your code is most likely creating an instance of whichever class you pass - *i.e.* it is calling `HistoricCVSHandler` internally to create an instance of that class.

We normally think of Python objects as instances of some class. Classes are similarly objects, and in fact are instances of their so-called *metaclass*, which by default will be `type` for classes inheriting from object.

```
>>> class MyClass(object): pass
... 
>>> type(MyClass)
<type 'type'>
```

Answer (score 0):

A link to the code would be useful, but in python you can pass uninstantiated objects around like this just fine. i.e.:

```
def f(uninst_class, arg):
     return uninst_class(arg)
```

Comment: The object you passed into `f` is an instance of the `class type`, so it isn't really uninstantiated...

Answer (score 0):

Think of python variables as labels, you can label a class (no instance), its like giving an alias to that class.

```
>>> class A(): pass
>>> A
<class __builtin__.A at 0x000001BE82279D08>
>>> b = A
>>> b
<class __builtin__.A at 0x000001BE82279D08>
>>> a = b()
>>> a
<__builtin__.A instance at 0x000001BE82269F48>
>>> A()
<__builtin__.A instance at 0x000001BE82269708>
```

Its the same with funtions parameters, you can pass a class (no instance) to the function for posterior use of it.

```
>>> def instantiator(c):
...     return c()
...     
>>> c = instantiator(b)
>>> c
<__builtin__.A instance at 0x000001BE8226A148>
>>> c = instantiator(A)
>>> c
<__builtin__.A instance at 0x000001BE8226A288>
```